# "Good"="many" in "qualified with good years of teaching experience"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the probability of "good" being interpreted to mean "many" rather than "positive" in this particular sentence:

*All the teachers are Professionally qualified with good years of teaching experience.*

Comment: I think that usage of *good* is erroneous.

Comment: *Good* is not about positivity here, as in -- **good** 5.1 Used to emphasize that a number is at least as great as one claims: they’re a good twenty years younger (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/good) -- even without a number, *good* here implies 'fair number of,' '(more than) enough' ... as also answered by @Elian below.

Answer (score 1):

"All the teachers are professionally qualified with good years of teaching experience"  is grammatically correct.

What is meant by "good years" is "ample (or *fairly long*) years."

> **[good](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/good)**: sufficient; ample; fairly large or long.

Consider this other example:

> We have a **good** [=ample, sufficient] supply of food.

Comment: Let's be a bit more specific and stick to the specific context I provided and the specific question I asked. :-)

Comment: +1 Yes, though usually it's *good number of*.

Comment: @Runglish Also, see my comment at the Question.

Answer (score 1):

The use of 'good' in this sentence sounds clumsy or at least ambiguous in UK English usage. Either 'many' or 'a good number of' as noted in the earlier answer would be a better choice in the sentence.